# Creating a longer page in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am creating a revision app and I want to add notes to the app. 
How do I add lots of text to one screen (I have already tried adding a `TextView` but there is not enough room to fit it all in is there a way to make the screen longer (with a scroll down))?

I am new to android and your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Embed the entire screen in a ScrollView.

Comment: you can use a webview instead..

Answer (score 0):

use scrollview inside linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="mytexts"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    />
        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make your screen scrollabel by adding just a few lines in 
AndroidManifest.xml. Here is an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="540dp"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:text="Forward"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Back"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="eft"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cam0"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ScrollView>
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"/>

 </ScrollView>
```

set `width` and `height` to `wrap_content` and `singleLine` to `false`;